# Segmentation fault when attempting to create a custom C++/CUDA function for PyTorch

Tags: python, c++, pytorch

I'm trying to create a custom function for PyTorch and I started with a simple example. I tried to follow the basic layout as in this link: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html, but I get a segmentation fault error when I try to run an example. I have 4 files below that implement my test:

**simple_cuda.cpp**

```
#include <torch/extension.h>

// CUDA declarations

torch::Tensor cuda_vec_sum(
    torch::Tensor x,
    torch::Tensor y);

// C++ interface

#define CHECK_CUDA(x) TORCH_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
#define CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x) TORCH_CHECK(x.is_contiguous(), #x " must be contiguous")
#define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)

torch::Tensor vec_sum(
    torch::Tensor x,
    torch::Tensor y) {
        CHECK_INPUT(x);
        CHECK_INPUT(y);

        return cuda_vec_sum(x, y);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m) {
  m.def("sum", &vec_sum, "VECSUM (CUDA)");
}
```

This declares the functions and does some boiler plate checks, and also uses pybind11 so that I can import the functions in python.

**simple_cuda_kernel.cu**

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

template <typename scalar_t>
__global__ void cuda_vec_sum_kernel(
    const scalar_t* __restrict__ x,
    const scalar_t* __restrict__ y,
    scalar_t* __restrict__ z,
    size_t N) {

    const int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (index < N) {
        z[index] = x[index] + y[index];
    }
}

torch::Tensor cuda_vec_sum(torch::Tensor x, torch::Tensor y) {

    auto z = torch::zeros_like(x);

    AT_DISPATCH_FLOATING_TYPES(x.type(), "cuda_vec_sum", ([&] {
        cuda_vec_sum_kernel<scalar_t><<<1, 1>>>(
            x.data<scalar_t>(),
            y.data<scalar_t>(),
            z.data<scalar_t>(),
            x.size(0));
    }));

    printf("Error: %s", cudaGetLastError());

    return z;
}
```

This file contains the cuda kernel and the actual function definition. Also, it will print the error that happens in the cuda kernel.

**simple_setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension

setup(
    name='simple_cuda',
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension('simple_cuda', [
            'simple_cuda.cpp',
            'simple_cuda_kernel.cu',
        ])
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    })
```

This file does all the setup. Used command "python simple_setup.py install" to compile.

**simple_test.py**

```
import torch
import simple_cuda

assert torch.cuda.is_available()
cuda_device = torch.device('cuda:0')

N = 100000
x = torch.ones(N, device=cuda_device, dtype=torch.float)
y = torch.ones(N, device=cuda_device, dtype=torch.float)

import time
start = time.time()
print(simple_cuda.sum(x, y))
end = time.time()
print(f"Full sum done in {end-start} seconds")
```

This is where I run a quick test, and I get a segmentation fault error.

I have the following packages installed: CUDAcore/11.1.1, GCCcore/10.2.0, GMP/6.1.2, Boost/1.72.0, GCC/10.2.0, CUDA/11.1.1 (Some of these may be irrelevant). What is going wrong with this?